# How to replay animation chart.js

Tags: jquery-animate, chart.js

How is it possible to replay the animation on a chart create with chart.js ?
Is there a specific function ? Or may I recall and reconstruct my chart ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of how to do this within chart.js but if you provide code I maybe able to help further.

You could put your chart within a setInterval, if you create it outside the setInterval it will be shown on page load and then again within the setInterval and it will be repeated at the specified time.

Further information on setInterval is available here - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp.

Comment: Thank you, but when I say "replay". I mean this with an action like a clic or other event. Not a loop replay ;-)